# On an iPad, can I "markup and reply" to two PDFS in the same email?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, attachments, markup

If someone sends me an email containing a PDF attachment (or a JPG, or another image format...) I know that, on an iPad, I can markup the attachment and then send the marked-up document in a reply to the sender.  But what if the email contains *two* PDFs?  Is there a way to mark up the first, return to the original email, mark up the second, then send a reply containing both marked-up documents?

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time.

1. Save both to Files
2. Mark up with abandon
3. Reply and attach

This works in Outlook, native mail, and the fastmail iOS/iPadOS app.

Comment: This obviously works, and solves my problem, but there's something very fluid about tapping an attachment, marking it up, and sending it back without ever having to leave Mail, and I was hoping for a similar workflow here.